# Hot edit hardware keyboard long press popup?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have usb keyboard using with my android 2.3. Can I change popup simbols? I try to modify LatinIME, but it's takes effect only with virtual (on-screen) keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend a lot of time to search it. All you need /frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/method/QwertyKeyListener.java from android source.